# Help function ? sometimes doesn't show help

Tags: front-end, information-function

I was just wondering if this is a known bug.  When I want to get basic help using the `?` command before some function name, it typically works for a while, but I've noticed that after I've computed some stuff (like, around 150 or so inputs), *Mathematica* doesn't pull up the help, but instead just lists the attributes of the command.  I'm running version 9.0.1 on OS 10.9.3, but this was also happening on an entirely different system with an older OS (10.6.8 I believe).  If I restart the kernel, it works again.  If I can reproduce the problem, I will post a screenshot.

---

**Addendum**.  I have now been able to take a screenshot of the issue:
[image]

Comment: I've noted that sometimes help gets unresponsive (in my case, highlight/right-click help) and I have to try a few times. Very occasionally, it just stops working and I have to restart kernel. Perhaps related. In any case, `bugs` tag is for *confirmed*/*reproduced (possible)* bugs only - edited.

Comment: More often than not I use F1 (i.e. the documentation center) rather than `Information`. Cannot reproduce on Windows 7 V9.01. Can you reproduce it using something like `Do[Information[Plot], {150}]`?

Comment: Can not reproduce on 8.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (October 10, 2011).

Comment: @Johu Thanks for the feedback.  Unfortunately, this is an intermittent issue that doesn't happen very often, but it is very strange and sort of inconvenient.  As you can see by the size of the `In[]` value, it took over 200 inputs before I observed this issue.  Sometimes it takes more, sometimes less, and sometimes not at all.

Comment: @heropup Yes I went to 300. Maybe you could make a notebook which gives error with a high frequency and share it.

Comment: I've never seen this (M9.0.1, OSX10.9.3), but I've heard others complain about the same.